# Assignment of a temporary object vs. move assignment

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Clang-tidy gives me a hint when I trying to use move assignment for 
a temporary object:

> Moving a temporary object prevents copy elision

How it works? It's something like RVO?

Example:

```
class address {
public:
    // CST
    address(address&&) noexcept;

public:
    static address make_address(...);
};

const auto next_address = std::move(
                          ^ Hint point to this expression
    address::make_address(...));
```

Comment: A function's return value is already an rvalue expression. The purpose of `std::move` is to "convert" an expression to an rvalue. So it adds nothing here.

Comment: @lubgr, yes, thanks for the tip! I think this is the one.